# Parsing dictionary object in JSON response inside fetch

Tags: javascript

I am having Javascript code that works fine when the server returns a simple string
i.e. backend was using

```
"body": json.dumps(string_object),
```

Javascript code that worked:

```
fetchRetry(`${API_ENDPOINT}?prompt=${prompt}&model=${model}`, 10000,6, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
      }).then((response) =>{
          console.log("RESPONSE")
          return response.json()
      }).then((data) => {
          console.log("DATA")
          return JSON.parse(data);
      }).then((data) => {        
          // Process data here
      }).catch(function(error){
        console.log("Got error)
      });;
    });
```

I have now modified the backend to return a dictionary

```
"body": json.dumps(dictionary),
```

In the response in my browser, I can see it coming as:

```
[{"text": "Sample 1", "sentiment": "Negative"}, {"text": "Sample 2", "sentiment": "Negative"}, {"text": "Sample 3", "sentiment": "Positive"}, {"text": "Sample 4", "sentiment": "Positive"}, {"text": "Sample 5", "sentiment": "Positive"}]
```

However inside the fetchRetry call, I am getting the response promise, but it doesn't enter the "then((data)" and goes into the catch block. Here's what comes on the console:

```
RESPONSE
twitter.js:93 Got error
```

I am not a Javascript developer, can someone help me to make this work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `.json()` on a Response, that will *automatically* call `JSON.parse` on the response text to turn it into an array (or an object, or into whatever it turns out to be). Parsing it *again* with `JSON.parse` doesn't make sense, and may well throw (or produce malformed output).

Use:

```
fetchRetry(`${API_ENDPOINT}?prompt=${prompt}&model=${model}`, 10000,6, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
}).then(response => response.json())
  .then((data) => {        
    // Process data here
  }).catch(function(error){
    console.log("Got error", error);
  });
```

Just in case there are errors, make sure to log what they are, for easier debugging.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Since i had a print statement before the parsing, I was expecting it to at least print the statement before going into the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse the data again as `response.json` will parse it.

> **json()** is a function that reads the response stream to completion and parses the response as json. This operation may take time, so instead of just returning the json, it returns another Promise. The success function of this promise will have the resulting parsed json as an argument

Try this.

```
fetchRetry(`${API_ENDPOINT}?prompt=${prompt}&model=${model}`, 10000, 6, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
}).then(response => {
    console.log("RESPONSE");
    return response.json();
}).then(data => {
    console.log("DATA")
    // Process data here
}).catch(error => {
    console.log("Got error);
});
```